# Spring : Copy objects without setting mappings to null.

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which I would like to copy objects for copy-functionality. I have been using `BeanUtils` from `springFramework` and it's working nice. The only problem is I have to manually set not to copy all the mapped objects which are associated to the object. If I don't do that, I get an error that there is already an entry existing for the mapped object in DB.

How can I remedy this problem?

Code :

```
GroupCanvas destinationGroupCanvas = new GroupCanvas();
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(groupCanvas,destinationGroupCanvas);
destinationGroupCanvas.setMcanvasid(0);
// Below ones are the mappings as described in the model
destinationGroupCanvas.setFavoriteCanvasSet(null);
destinationGroupCanvas.setOwnedsection(null);
```

GroupCanvas model mappings:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "currentcanvas", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<GroupSection> ownedsection = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "favoriteCanvases", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<FavoriteCanvas> favoriteCanvasSet = new HashSet<>();
```

I don't want to manually specify not to copy associations. This is helpful in maintenance, so I don't have to come back to this code again and add a line to it everytime I change the GroupCanvas model or similar. What can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ignore properties that you don't want to copy by specifying third parameter to [BeanUtils.copyProperties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html)

```
copyProperties(Object source, Object target, String[] ignoreProperties)
```

> This method will copy the property values of the given source bean
>   into the given target bean, ignoring the given "ignoreProperties".

We will normally use [Converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) in our project to convert one type of object to another type.

Comment: I am not converting object from one type to other, I am copying. The ignoreProperties sounds good, but that would also mean for any changes in mappings I would have to hunt down in all places where I am copying Objects and change the ignoreProperties....

Comment: @WeareBorg how do you let your utility know about don't copy certain properties without having to specify them, Are you looking for anything specific, or do you have any thing in your mind that you wish to have in spring

Comment: I was expecting that JsonIgnored properties won't be automatically ignored in the first-place... I am just looking for a way to specify to ignore all properties for copying which are annotated with @JsonIgnore

Comment: @WeareBorg You intention is good.. but there is a possible gap as you are using Spring's BeanUtils method and jackson's @JsonIgnore. I do not recommed but there is way using jackson to convert your Bean to Json string usign object mapper (so that it will ignore @jsonIgnore  properites) and then convert the bean back to java class `note: I will recommend it`